# Just me or is SO a bit slower than usual?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, performance

Recently it seems like stackoverflow is going a bit slower than usual. I'm getting GET / times of about 800ms. For meta.stackoverflow GET / is only taking about 300ms. Why the difference? Is there server maintenance going on?

Also, 800ms doesn't seem like much, but it's a noticeable lag for me.

Comment: Hmm, no, haven't noticed, not really. But possibly any page load < 1 sec is too fast to register with me? (as I browsed on a slooooow GPRS connection today, so anything faster will seem lightning-fast now I am on a fat pipe)

Comment: @Pisk well the thing is that total page load time here is taking about 2.5 seconds, and for meta about 1.3 seconds. One second of difference for similar sites. (that's according to Firebug)

Comment: hmm, you could be right: the right sidebar seems to be loading slower than usual, but as I mostly ignore it, I haven't noticed (as site is quite usable for me even while that is still loading).

Answer (score 1):

I seemed to notice a small DNS lookup delay when first accessing a new SE domain, but that was an hour or so ago.